# How to create a CSS style which override another CSS style

Tags: html, css

I have 2 CSS styles which pretty much the same except one specific 'width' and the other does not. How can I create a CSS style which inherits another CSS style but override a property?

```
  .FirstStyle
    {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 8px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;

        height: 29px;
        width: 5px;

        float: left;
    }


    .SecondStyle
    {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 8px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;

        height: 29px;

        float: left;
    }
```

Comment: If you're talking about how to reduce code duplication, CSS doesn't have this ability (yet). Preprocessors such as LESS and Sass can do this with mixins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do try this way

In the two class above the width is not defined

```
.FirstStyle, .SecondStyle
{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 8px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

    height: 29px;
    width: 5px;

    float: left;
}
```

Here you define the width only for the FirstStyle Class .. (and anyway do the fact this class is below the others could override an eventually width specified above )

```
.FirtsStyle
{
    width: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the above solution. But some how FirstStyle does not have the property 'height' and 'float'. When I debug in Chrome developer tool. In the comupted style of the element with FirstStyle, the float is 'none' and height is 0.  Do you have any idea? Width is correct though.

Answer (score 0):

**How can I create a CSS style which inherits another CSS style but override a property?**

The succeeding css styling automatically overrides the preceding property so just add the property below the one you want to override and it'll inherit everything except the new styling specified.

**Example:**

HTML:

```
<div class="someClass anotherClass">
   ....
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.someClass {
    width: 100px;
    color: green;
}
.anotherClass {
    width: 200px; <-- This will override the above values
    color: red;
}
.someClass {
    width: 450px !important; <-- The !important tag will override both suceeding as well as preceeding properties
}
.someClass {
    width: 500px; <-- This will override the first two styling properties
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the [CSS specificity value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

[image]

1. If the element has inline styling, that automatically wins (1,0,0,0
   points)
2. For each ID value, apply 0,1,0,0 points
3. For each class value (or pseudo-class or attribute selector), apply
   0,0,1,0 points
4. For each element reference, apply 0,0,0,1 point

---

**Notes**

1. The universal selector (*) has no specificity value (0,0,0,0)
2. Pseudo-elements (e.g. `:first-line`) get 0,0,0,1 unlike their
   pseudo-class brethren which get 0,0,1,0
3. The pseudo-class `:not()` adds no specificity by itself, only what's
   inside it's parentheses.
4. The `!important` value appended a CSS property value is an automatic
   win. It overrides even inline styles from the markup. The only way
   an `!important` value can be overridden is with another !important
   rule declared later in the CSS and with equal or great specificity
   value otherwise. You could think of it as adding 1,0,0,0,0 to the
   specificity value